# How to properly wait for the yum lock to be released?

Tags: linux, cron, redhat, yum

I'm trying to write a cronjob that updates packages from a given yum repository on a regular basis by running the following command:

```
yum -q -e 0 -d 0 -y update --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='my-yum-repo'
```

In order to prevent "yum lock warnings" like the following...

```
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 4902.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  42 M RSS (325 MB VSZ)
    Started: Wed Apr  3 01:10:07 2019 - 00:01 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 4902
```

... I tried to enclose my code in a while loop to check for the existence of the yum.pid file as follow:

```
*/5 * * * *  root while [ -f /var/run/yum.pid ]; do sleep 1; done && yum -q -e 0 -d 0 -y update --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='my-yum-repo'
```

Unfortunately, from time to time, the "yum lock warnings" still appear.

I also tried it that way and the "yum lock warnings" still appear from time to time:

```
while [ `pgrep 'yum|rhn_check'` ]; do sleep 1; done && yum -q -e 0 -d 0 -y update --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='my-yum-repo'
```

Do you have an idea how I could prevent them to occur? I would like to avoid redirecting stdout to /dev/null because I need to be informed if "real" problems occur during packages update.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can check processlist if yum is currently running and continue after exiting process completed.

```
numProcess=` ps -ef | grep 'yum' | grep -v 'grep' | wc`

while [[ numProcess -gt 0 ]]
do
     sleep 5;
done

yum -q -e 0 -d 0 -y update --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='my-yum-repo'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also tried it in a similar way (see my edits above) and the "yum lock warnings" still appear from time to time.

Comment: This code is not working for me.  I solved with a 
while [[ `pgrep yum` -gt 0 ]]
    do
         sleep 5;
    done